# How many people died in the 5th and 6th episodes?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, moon-knight-2022

In the 5th episode of the 2022 *Moon Knight* TV show, purple streaks of light in the sky of the Egyptian afterlife show that Harrow and his followers are sending souls back earlier than their time. It seems like quite a few to me, and it's suggested that it's still happening during the time the protagonists are trying to escape the afterlife. Is there any background material indicating just how many souls were lost? This being the MCU, I'm sure the effect was relatively minor compared to The Battle of New York, or The Snap, but I'm curious as to whether there are any numbers.

Comment: _”Let us purify the souls of Cairo and then the world.”_ - they only did it at Cairo that we see and even that didn’t seem too many, relatively speaking.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: I do suspect that was the case, but I am curious as to how far it did go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understood, those were the souls of the Egyptian patrol unit that stopped Harrow and his crew during the events of episode 6. Harrow then used his staff and the power of Ammit to kill the soldiers, but one of them survived because his soul was pure. These events in episode 6 happen at the same time as episode 5, so it makes sense that these are the souls Mark and Steven saw in the afterlife, as these where the only souls we saw Harrow get rid of during Mark and Steven's stay in the afterlife. Not all the soldiers are visible in the same frame, but I counted at least 13 soldiers, and you can see the whole scene in [this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0KhTSw2I2Pc)[image]

One of the soldiers survived, so that means that at least 12 souls were sent to the after life in the scene in episode 5/6.

Comment: This only really answers part of the question, we see Harrow using the staff to cleanse Cairo as well in episode 6.

Comment: I think this may be as close to an answer as we'll get in the near future.